# Improper redirection in apache for subdomain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, webfaction

I'm currently trying to redirect a webfaction app to another one hosted under a different URL.

This is what I've got so far

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^foo\.barbaz\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://barbaz.com/foo%{REQUEST_URI} [R=permanent,L]
```

That works properly for anything like

```
http://foo.barbaz.com/noideawhatimdoing => http://barbaz.com/foo/noideawhatimdoing
```

But fails miserably when using only the root url.

```
http://foo.barbaz.com/ => http://foo.barbaz.com/absolute/path/to/folder/foo/absolute/path/to/folder/foo/absolute/path/to/folder/foo/...
```

Note that /foo is appended to the absolute path to the .htaccess file and that complete string is added multiple times to the resulting url, which has exactly the same HTTP_HOST.

I have tried RedirectBase and FollowSymLinks, but none seem to do the trick.

Any ideas? Really not an expert in apache, as you can tell.

Thanks.

A.

Comment: Make sure this is your very first rule.

Comment: I have a previous rule redirecting any http:// requests on a domain and subdomains to https. Would this count? Do I need a different app if it does?

Comment: Yes better to keep this rule as very first rule.

Comment: Thanks! This worked. If you want you can add this as an answer and I'll check it as the correct answer. --A

Comment: sure I posted my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure to place this permanent redirect as **very first rule** in your .htaccess so that this rule is not impacted by other rules.